# How to make a definition list in TeX

Tags: lists, itemize, definition

I want to make a list similar to the following in HTML, but in LaTeX:

```
<dl><dt>Foo</dt>
<dd>Bar</dd>
<dd>Baz</dd>
<dt>Things I do</dt>
<dd>Can Haz</dd>
<dd>Like trains</dd></dl>
```

which I would like to have look like http://jsbin.com/xutokeraka/edit?html,css,output.

What is the easiest way to generate something like that without having to define it all on my own? Or should I just define my own list style with `itemize`?

Comment: It is called `description`, see the `enumitem` package for options as to configure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed, labelwidth=\linewidth, font =\sffamily\itshape\bfseries, listparindent =0pt, before =\sffamily]
\item[Foo]

Bar 

Baz

  \item[Things I do]
        Can Haz

        Like Trains
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]